# What can I expect from this pc when producing audio?

Tags: audio-recording, daw, computer, tech-specs

Quick specs:

8 GB RAM

256 SSD drive

and the weak part, CPU: Intel Celeron J1900 quad-core 2 GHz (turbo-boost up to 2.41 GHz)

It’s a bargain laptop from aliexpress for 325 bucks [here](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/8GB-RAM-256GB-SSD-Quad-Core-Laptop-Computer-Notebook-14-Inch-1600-900-Screen-Bluetooth-WIFI/32511862090.html?spm=2114.30010308.3.9.VlDNMO&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_0%2Csearchweb201602_5_10057_10056_10055_10037_10049_10033_10032_10058_10017_405_404_407_10040%2Csearchweb201603_8&btsid=7869b58e-b62f-4d28-bd9d-bd6537a12f1d)

What job can it do when working with DAWs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- less tracks per project.
- less plugins opened.
- if you use your factory soundcard (the one on your motherboard) you'll probably suffer from latency and a bad signal/noise ratio.

But you still can definitely work with it (music, mixing, and even small movie project(s)).

FYI : when a computer is too limitated for your work, don't forget you can always render your track(s) into audio files to reprocess them (destructive treatment).

Comment: You can render/bounce to audio for playback, but keep the original track & disable it, so you can change your mind later, or open it all up again on a bigger mix machine. Cubase has a freeze function which will easily do that inline, idk about other DAWs.